# my ostream operator cannot outputing data from private data member with const by using specific function

Tags: c++

I am trying to output data from a private member, Result results[], by using ostream operator and a function.

The ostream operator cannot be friend and needs to be const.

The issue I am facing is the function I used to read the private member in ostream, only can run while the operator removes its const. is there any way to solve it?

```
header file

#ifndef REGIST_H
#define REGIST_H

#include "Result.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const unsigned MaxResults = 10;


class Registration {
public:
    Registration();

    int calculateCredit() const;
    long GetStudentId() const;
    int GetCount() const;
    int GetSem() const;

    Result& resultIndex(int index) {    // the function I used to input 
        return results[index];          // and output data
    }

    void SetStudentId(long si);
    void SetCount(int sc);
    void SetSem(int sm);



private:
    long studentId;           
    int semester;          
    int count;             
    Result results[MaxResults];
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os,const Registration & R); 
// this is the part I mentioned, I need const but the program can only run without it

istream& operator >>(istream& input,Registration& R);

#endif



cpp file

#include "Registration.h"
#include <sstream>

Registration::Registration()
{
    count = 0;
}


int Registration::calculateCredit() const {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < GetCount(); i++)
        sum += results[i].units.GetCredits();

    return sum;
}

long Registration::GetStudentId() const {
    return studentId;
}

int Registration::GetCount() const {
    return count;
}

int Registration::GetSem() const {
    return semester;
}

void Registration::SetStudentId(long si) {
    studentId = si;
}

void Registration::SetCount(int sc) {
    count = sc;
}

void Registration::SetSem(int sm) {
    semester = sm;
}


istream& operator >>(istream& input, Registration& R) {

    string inputStuID;
    string inputSem;
    string inputCount;


    getline(input, inputStuID);
    getline(input, inputSem);
    getline(input, inputCount);

    long stID;
    int sem;
    int countNumber;

    stringstream a(inputStuID);
    stringstream b(inputSem);
    stringstream c(inputCount);

    a >> stID;
    b >> sem;
    c >> countNumber;

    R.SetStudentId(stID);
    R.SetSem(sem);
    R.SetCount(countNumber);


    for (int i = 0; i < countNumber; i++) {
        input >> R.resultIndex(i);  // input function ok
    }
    return input;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Registration& R) { 


    Result result;
    os << "Student ID: " << R.GetStudentId() << '\n'
        << "Semester:   " << R.GetSem() << '\n';

    os << "Results:\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < R.GetCount(); i++) {
        os << i + 1 << ". ";
        os << R.resultIndex(i) << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

Compiler issues:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2662   'Result &Registration::resultIndex(int)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Registration' to 'Registration &'   Lab4    C:\Users\qiyul\Desktop\VisualStudio\Lab4\Lab4\Registration.cpp  86

Comment: ot: once you return a non-const reference you can also make the member `public`

Answer (score 1):

> The ostream operator needs to be const.

Then provide const access to the data it requires.

e.g. by adding a `const` overload

```
Result& Registration::resultIndex(int index) { // overload for writing
    return results[index];
}

const Result& Registration::resultIndex(int index) const { // overload for reading
    return results[index];
}
```

> The ostream operator cannot be friend

Why not? It's logically part of the class. It's also very suspicious that your `<<` doesn't format things that your `>>` can consume.

I would expect these members to be some thing like:

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream& input, Registration& R) {

    input >> R.studentId >> R.semester >> R.count;

    for (int i = 0; i < R.count; i++) {
        input >> R.results[i];     }
    return input;
}

friend ostream& operator <<(ostream & output, const Registration& R) {
    output << R.studentId << '\n' << R.semester << '\n' << R.count << "\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < R.count; i++) {
        output << R.results[i] << '\n';
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: cause that's what my exercise ask for

Comment: sadly cannot, adding the const shows the issues I just stated on top, and "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Result' (or there is no acceptable conversion) Lab4 C:\Users\qiyul\Desktop\VisualStudio\Lab4\Lab4\Registration.cpp 72 
"

Comment: @qiyu you can add `const` to `<<` if you have a `const resultIndex`

Comment: if using the results in the stream, the compiler shows it is inaccessible

Comment: @qiyu I'm showing what I would expect those members to look like. `<<` is not pretty-print

Comment: thank you but my exercise wants me to not use friend function

Comment: @lll you only need the first part